# Multiplying each column of a dataframe with each corresponding value across rows of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes as follows:

```
df1 

   A            B           C
1 -0.0003829968 0.003792229 0.00506061
2 -0.0029670165 0.029034423 0.03683273
3 -0.0096666141 0.093444961 0.11605309
4 -0.0222262302 0.210496253 0.25934497 
5 -0.0423132265 0.391343634 0.47830584
...           ...         ...
(3 columns x 500 rows)

df2 

   A           B          C
V1 -22.0445023 68.2904587 42.73254395
V2 37.1982040 102.7727966 62.52117538
V3 -12.7489920 86.8897324 23.78104782
V4 -5.8218970 57.2676620 46.14707565
V5 -33.5733528 9.4771776 -54.59719086
...            ...       ...
(3 columns x 4338 rows)
```

I am looking to multiply each column of df1 by the corresponding value of df2 which is in the same column, row-by-row. So, something like this:

```
df3
    
   X (df1$A * df2$A[V1])        Y (df1$B * df2$B[V1])      Z (df1$C * df2$C[V1])      ... 
1 (-0.0003829968 * -22.0445023) (0.003792229 * 68.2904587) (0.00506061 * 42.73254395)
2 (-0.0029670165 * -22.0445023) (0.029034423 * 68.2904587) (0.03683273 * 42.73254395) 
3 (-0.0096666141 * -22.0445023) (0.093444961 * 68.2904587) (0.11605309 * 42.73254395)        
4 (-0.0222262302 * -22.0445023) (0.210496253 * 68.2904587) (0.25934497 * 42.73254395)       
5 (-0.0423132265 * -22.0445023) (0.391343634 * 68.2904587) (0.47830584 * 42.73254395)   
(13014 columns x 500 rows)
```

And so the next cols would be (df1$A * df2$A[V2]) (df1$B * df2$B[V2]) (df1$C * df2$C[V2]) and so on, for each value in each row in df2.

I couldn't find a solution to this specific question, so apologies if this is a repeat.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an exact answer for you, but consider turning your data frames into matrices and then looking at the `outer` function.  I think this will make the columns of the new dataframe that you want but you will need to put them in the right order.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try this method.