# Subsetting a dataframe with columns of interest in an unusual pattern

Tags: r

I currently have a dataframe which is 500 rows x 39042 columns in size. Essentially I would like to subset a specific sequence of columns in this data frame which are in the following pattern:

1, 4, 7, 8, 11, 14, 15, 18, 21 ....

[The file is too large for R so I have attached a picture of what the data looks like in Excel. The columns in red are the ones I would like to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SN8w.png)

I have thought about stacking the dataframe every 9 columns (so the data will follow a consistent pattern), subsetting only the three columns of interest and re-formatting to a wide format, but I don't know how to do this. There was a similar question posted previously about stacking columns, ([Automatically stack every nth column of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841179/automatically-stack-every-nth-column-of-a-dataframe)) but that was for a small dataframe and I am having issues using the answers posted there on my data.

If you need any more info please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: what defines the pattern there?and do you mean you want to get out those *n* columns and then stack them vertically? If you could create a piece of code with a dummy input and desired output for that it would be helpful

Comment: See my previous question which defines how this pattern came to be.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70020767/multiplying-each-column-of-a-dataframe-with-each-corresponding-value-across-rows)

Essentially I used the outer function to cross-multiply between two dataframes, but this gave me columns for every column multiplied by every row, and not a specific column multiplied by a specific row, which is what was needed. This does produce the data I am after, but it is just a part of a larger dataframe.

I will create some dummy code, no problem.

Comment: which of those columns are being selected?

Comment: If the number of columns `n <- ncol(df)`, then the index to subset `i <- sort(c(seq(1, n, by = 7), seq(4, n, by = 7), seq(7, n, by = 7)))`. You can subset the data frame `new_df <- df[,i]`

Comment: Do you mean for data frames involved with the outer function? It selected each column in df1 and multiplied it by each value in each row in df2.

Comment: The method by Mohanasundaram worked, it just needed some changes to the values. I'm happy to accept this as the answer. Thanks!